# Compare columns of a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have a CSV file as such

```
ID  OLD_A  NEW_A  OLD_B     NEW_B     OLD_C  NEW_C
1   0      0      1/1/2017  1/1/2017  ABC    BCD
2   0      0      1/1/2017  2/1/2017  ABC    ABC
3   1      2      1/1/2017  1/1/2017  ABC    BCD
```

I want to compare the old and new columns for A,B and C and in case there's a difference in the value of OLD and NEW (there's 10k+ rows) , I want return an output as such (from above example):

```
ID Field_Changed OLD_Value   NEW_Value
1  C             ABC         BCD
2  B             1/1/2017    2/1/2017
3  A             1           2
3  C             ABC         BCD
```

So far I've used the .loc method of pandas.DataFrame which returns the indexed location of the rows that qualify the boolean indexing, but I need the values as well...

```
df.loc[(df['OLD_A'] != df['NEW_A'])].index)
```

I'm new to python scripting and cannot seem to figure the logic out. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and create `MultiIndex` by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column names

[`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and rename column

filter with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
df = df.set_index('ID')

df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df.stack()[['OLD','NEW']].reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Field_Changed'})
print (df1)
   ID Field_Changed       OLD       NEW
0   1             A         0         0
1   1             B  1/1/2017  1/1/2017
2   1             C       ABC       BCD
3   2             A         0         0
4   2             B  1/1/2017  2/1/2017
5   2             C       ABC       ABC
6   3             A         1         2
7   3             B  1/1/2017  1/1/2017
8   3             C       ABC       BCD

print (df1.columns)
Index(['ID', 'Field_Changed', 'OLD', 'NEW'], dtype='object')

print (df1.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=9, step=1)
```

```
print (df1['OLD'] != df1['NEW'])
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7    False
8     True
dtype: bool

df2 = df1[df1['OLD'] != df1['NEW']]
print (df2)
   ID Field_Changed       OLD       NEW
2   1             C       ABC       BCD
4   2             B  1/1/2017  2/1/2017
6   3             A         1         2
8   3             C       ABC       BCD
```

Comment: Thanks , but I seem to get this error ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names

Comment: Hmm, `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)` this return error? What is `print (df.columns)` after this code?

Comment: That line is fine, its this line which returns an error df2 = df1[df1['OLD'] != df1['NEW']]

Comment: are you sure? Because it seems error is in `df1 = df.stack()`. Can you test it?

Comment: yes I'm sure, df2 = df1[df1['OLD'] != df1['NEW']] is where the error seems to pop up. Sorry about this, really appreciate your help. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Ok, so what return `print (df1)` ? Nice `DataFrame` with no `Multiindex` in columns or in `index`? Check it by `df1.columns` and `df1.index`.

Comment: Because I never see this error in boolen indexing. there has to be something different between your real data solution and this sample.

Comment: my date values look like this '12/17/2016 8:00:00 AM' Could this be the issue?

Comment: I think no. What return `df1['OLD'] != df1['NEW']` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134556/discussion-between-kage77-and-jezrael).

Comment: THIS WORKS! There was a rogue '_' which was  causing this issue. YOU ARE AWESOME! cant thank you enough!!!